# Couldn't get connection factory client ANDROID GOOGLE MAP

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.locdroid_v2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>   

        <permission android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />



            <activity
                android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.Connexion"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.Inscription"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.Rapide"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>

           <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.Map"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>

            <meta-data 
                 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
                 android:value="MyKey"/>

             <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@+integer/google_play_services_version" />

           </application>


    </manifest>
```

My XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="MyKey"
            android:clickable="true"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java 
    package com.example.locdroid_v2;

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class GoogleMap extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Google map doesn't display properly and only shows grid.
And there is only one error which is : Couldn't get connection factory client

Here are my librairies 
android-support-v4.jar
apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar
google-play-services_lib.jar
google-play-services.jar
httpmime-4.2.3.jar
osmdroid-android-1.04.jar
slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar

Can you help me pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and this

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="MyKey"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

is the old google maps library which is not what you want. you need google maps v2 library

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

Comment: Thank you. It was a library pb.